# Where to find Microsoft AutoUpdate on Mac?

Tags: mac, updates, auto-updates, microsoft

Hello to all that read this.

I want to delete the MAU application on my Mac. I’ve followed the various guides and deleted files. But the location given for the MAU application on my Mac is empty. It’s only a Microsoft folder, but no additional MAU folder. So I think Microsoft has moved it or hidden it somewhere else. Searching for it only gave the files which I already deleted.

Comment: Would you be more specific? Saying "on my Mac" is not specific enough... Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: What did you delete? Where was it? What OS, what version Office… etc etc… cos, frankly, it's split into so many components in different locations, you'd do better searching with something like [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware) [NOTE: doing this will probably pooch the entire update process so you'll forever be stuck on the same version]

Comment: Download [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) and use that to thoroughly delete an application in macOS.

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac (OS 12.1) with my version of Mac Office 2021, "MAU" is located at `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0/Microsoft AutoUpdate.app`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When Microsoft Autoupdate pops up again, just right-click on the icon in the dock, then go on 'Options' and 'Show in finder'. Then you can put that in the trash, as recommended here:

https://osxdaily.com/2019/07/20/how-delete-microsoft-autoupdate-mac/

I have two 'Library' folders on my MacBook for some reason, and MAU2.0 didn't appear in the one I was searching.